# Python regex matching with optional prefix and suffix

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that matches parts of a string (specifically peptide sequences with modifications) and I want to use re.findall to get all parts of the string:

The sequence can start with an optional suffix that is anything non-capital letter string followed by `-`.

And the sequence can also have a prefix that starts with a `-` followed by a non-capitial letter string.

The rest of the sequence should be split by capital letters with an optional prefix for each.

E.g.

`"foo-ABcmCD-bar"` -> `['foo-','A','B','cmC','D','-bar']`

`"DEF"` -> `['','D','E','F','']`

`"WHATEVER-foo"` -> `['', 'W', 'H', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'V', 'E', 'R', '-foo']`

`"cmC-foo"` -> `['', 'cmC', '-foo']`

`"ac-cmC-foo"` -> `['ac-', 'cmC', '-foo']`

What I have is:

```
(?:(^(?:[^A-Z]+-)?)|((?:-[^A-Z]+)?$)|((?:[^A-Z]*)?[A-Z]))
```

Capturing group 1 `(^(?:[^A-Z]+-)?)` is supposed to catch the optional prefix or an empty String.
Capturing group 2 `((?:-[^A-Z]+)?$)` is supposed to catch the optional suffix or an empty String.
Capturing group 3 `((?:[^A-Z]*)?[A-Z])` is supposed to catch any capital character in the rest of the string that could have a substring of non-capital characters in front.

I get the optional prefix or empty string.

The suffix seems almost to work -   BUT if there is a suffix the end of line is matched twice one with the suffix and ones with an empty string.

```
>>> re.findall(r,"foo-ABC-bar")
['foo-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-bar', '']
>>> re.findall(r,"ABC-bar")
['', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-bar', '']
>>> re.findall(r,"ABcmC")
['', 'A', 'B', 'cmC', '']
```

I.e. how do I get rid of the extra empty string or why is the $ matched twice?

example:
https://regex101.com/r/koZPOD/1

Comment: What is expected result for `foo-AB(-16)CDE-bla` ?

Comment: `re.findall(regex, 'foo-AB(-16)CDE-bla')` should return `['foo-', 'A', 'B', '(-16)C', 'D', 'E', '-bla']`

Comment: What about `re.split(r'([^A-Z]*(?:[A-Z]|$))', text)`?

Comment: `re.split(r'([^A-Z]*(?:[A-Z]|$))', text)` does not work, as it is not taking care the prefix and present suffix also seem to have the same problem of being matched plus an empty string

Comment: Why do you want an empty result `''` at the start?

Comment: the string can start with an prefix (e.g. `abc-`). If it is there, then it should be the first match. if it is not then the first match should be an empty string

Comment: `((?:-[^A-Z]+)?$)` matches empty string

Comment: Here is one more idea: [`(^)?[a-z]*[A-Z]($)?|^[a-z]+-|-[a-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/vQbZwg/3) - You can use it with [`finditer` (python demo)](https://tio.run/##hZA9a8MwEIZ3/YrDBCw1kenHFijBjV06dSilhRqnKLGUaLAkTurQkv/uSjYBD4VOd3rQPfdy7jucrLkbBt07iwFQEuIDeriHJlPWcrHfVtkKsktNrHw49NuK7wUmUtWPqbw/la/1W/3C44@sJaSTCpxALz@jj3q2JgC9CIeTTHKUhdKm00EixZzu2KYR/Ke9akr@0dIF25x3I1jyM5@aRb4Cz6IER0HTxlZZnJygzUWe9gBoNb2LI9ovR28YaA/GBni2Rq6ToxDOSdPRPGfjxAzNJ68Z@0t4@5/QoTaBRswISTF9ipgum/LN7zIMvw). Though it requires a bit result processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question already have three answers, all about how to write a regex that works, but none about how to fix your regex. Yours is almost correct: It just needs a tiny modification.

> [...] why is the `$` matched twice?

This is the relevant part:

```
(?:-[^A-Z]+)?$
```

As you see, you are matching an optional pattern before `$`, *a zero-width assertion*. That said, after matching `-bar` in `foo-A-bar`, the engine proceeds to the position right behind it, where it finds no `-[^A-Z]+` but, again, `$`. Since the former is optional, this is recorded as another match.

> [...] how do I get rid of the extra empty string[?]

We explicitly tell the engine to match `$` *iff* it is preceded by either `-[^A-Z]+` (i.e. has suffix), or something that is not `[^A-Z]` (i.e. no suffix):

```
(?:
  (^(?:[^A-Z]+-)?)
|
  ((?:-[^A-Z]+|(?<![^A-Z]))$)
|
  ((?:[^A-Z]*)?[A-Z])
)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZcCMXk/1).

<sub>(regex101.com's Python flavor doesn't reflect the actual result so I used PCRE2 instead.)</sub>

Also, the outermost `(?:` `)` and the `(?:` `)?` in `(?:[^A-Z]*)?` are unnecessary; you can remove them entirely. `(?<![^A-Z])` can also be simplified as `(?<=[A-Z])`.

```
(^(?:[^A-Z]+-)?)
|
((?:-[^A-Z]+|(?<=[A-Z]))$)
|
([^A-Z]*[A-Z])
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZcCMXk/2).

Remove the capturing groups to make it `.findall()`-friendly:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:[^A-Z]+-)?|(?:-[^A-Z]+|(?<=[A-Z]))$|[^A-Z]*[A-Z]')

for testcase in testcases:
  print(f'{testcase!r:<16}: {pattern.findall(testcase)}')
```

```py
'foo-ABcmCD-bar': ['foo-', 'A', 'B', 'cmC', 'D', '-bar']
'DEF'           : ['', 'D', 'E', 'F', '']
'WHATEVER-foo'  : ['', 'W', 'H', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'V', 'E', 'R', '-foo']
'foo-ABC-bar'   : ['foo-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-bar']
'ABC-bar'       : ['', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-bar']
'ABcmC'         : ['', 'A', 'B', 'cmC', '']
'foo-abCD'      : ['foo-', 'abC', 'D', '']
'abCD'          : ['', 'abC', 'D', '']
```

Comment: I believe you missed a part of question, they are looking to get rid of the leading and trailing empty values in the lists—e.g., `['', 'D', 'E', 'F', '']` should be `['D', 'E', 'F']`.  I recommended to remove all groups, it seems to work well.

Comment: @Reilas Quite the opposite. OP explicitly gave `['','D','E','F','']` in one of their examples. What they don't want is an extra empty string after the suffix (i.e. the last `''` in `['', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-bar', '']`) which I fully addressed in this answer.

Comment: Thanks works - guess I should have thought off "(?<=[A-Z]))". And yes I don't really need the capturing groups. I just put them here to be able to refer to the different parts of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

You could split using this regex:

```
(?<=[a-z]-)|(?<=[A-Z])|(?<=^)(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])|(?<![a-z])(?=-[a-z])
```

This matches the character position:

- `(?<=[a-z]-)` : after a lowercase letter and a `-`; OR
- `(?<=[A-Z])` : after an uppercase letter; OR
- `(?<=^)(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])` : after the beginning of string and before some number of lowercase letters then an uppercase letter; OR
- `(?<![a-z])(?=-[a-z])` : before a `-` not preceded by a lower case letter but followed by a lowercase letter

In python:

```py
strs = ['foo-ABcmCD-bar', 'DEF', 'WHATEVER-foo', 'foo-AB(-16)CDE-bla', 'foo-abCD', 'abCD', 'ABC-bar', 'ABcmC']
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-z]-)|(?<=[A-Z])|(?<=^)(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])|(?<![a-z])(?=-[a-z])')
for s in strs:
    print(f'{s!r:<20}: {regex.split(s)}')
```

Output:

```
'foo-ABcmCD-bar'    : ['foo-', 'A', 'B', 'cmC', 'D', '-bar']
'DEF'               : ['', 'D', 'E', 'F', '']
'WHATEVER-foo'      : ['', 'W', 'H', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'V', 'E', 'R', '-foo']
'foo-AB(-16)CDE-bla': ['foo-', 'A', 'B', '(-16)C', 'D', 'E', '-bla']
'foo-abCD'          : ['foo-', 'abC', 'D', '']
'abCD'              : ['', 'abC', 'D', '']
'ABC-bar'           : ['', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-bar']
'ABcmC'             : ['', 'A', 'B', 'cmC', '']
```

Comment: Not really the answer to the question - but a good solution to the problem - Thank you

Comment: I thought it worked but it fails on cases like `foo-abCD` (should return `['foo-','abC','D','']`) or `abCD` (should return `['','abC','D','']`)

Comment: @Lutz apologies for not answering the question; and apologies for not getting the regex quite right; I didn't do testing with data other than in the question. I've updated the regex to solve those issues.

Comment: @bobblebubble thanks. With the changes it's not necessary to reorder the terms in the regex as the negative lookahead on the last term now prevents it matching before the first term on the `foo-abCD` test case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - can't accept two answers - otherwise I would

Comment: No worries - I think you've accepted the right answer as it actually does answer your question rather than just offering an alternate solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could filter your regex results like this:

```
import re
strs = strs = ["foo-ABcmCD-bar", "DEF", "WHATEVER-foo", "foo-AB(-16)CDE-bla", 'foo-abCD', 'abCD']
for s in strs:
    result = (
        [[z for z in y if z] for y in (re.findall(r'(?:(^(?:[^A-Z]+-)?)|((?:-[^A-Z]+)?$)|((?:[^A-Z]*)?[A-Z]))', s))])
    print(f'1st step: {result=}')
    # result = result[:-1] if len(result) > 2 and result[-2] and '-' in result[-2][0] else result
    result = result[:-1] if len(result) > 2 and result[-2] and result[-2][0].startswith('-') else result # (better)
    print(f'2st step: {result=}')
    result = ['' if not x else x[0] for x in result]
    print(f'FINAL RESULT: 3rd step: {result=}')
    print('------------------')
    
1st step: result=[['foo-'], ['A'], ['B'], ['cmC'], ['D'], ['-bar'], []]
2st step: result=[['foo-'], ['A'], ['B'], ['cmC'], ['D'], ['-bar']]
FINAL RESULT: 3rd step: result=['foo-', 'A', 'B', 'cmC', 'D', '-bar']
------------------
1st step: result=[[], ['D'], ['E'], ['F'], []]
2st step: result=[[], ['D'], ['E'], ['F'], []]
FINAL RESULT: 3rd step: result=['', 'D', 'E', 'F', '']
------------------
1st step: result=[[], ['W'], ['H'], ['A'], ['T'], ['E'], ['V'], ['E'], ['R'], ['-foo'], []]
2st step: result=[[], ['W'], ['H'], ['A'], ['T'], ['E'], ['V'], ['E'], ['R'], ['-foo']]
FINAL RESULT: 3rd step: result=['', 'W', 'H', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'V', 'E', 'R', '-foo']
------------------
1st step: result=[['foo-'], ['A'], ['B'], ['(-16)C'], ['D'], ['E'], ['-bla'], []]
2st step: result=[['foo-'], ['A'], ['B'], ['(-16)C'], ['D'], ['E'], ['-bla']]
FINAL RESULT: 3rd step: result=['foo-', 'A', 'B', '(-16)C', 'D', 'E', '-bla']
```

As a one-liner (maybe more elegant - maybe not haha)

```
import re

strs = ["foo-ABcmCD-bar", "DEF", "WHATEVER-foo", "foo-AB(-16)CDE-bla", 'foo-abCD', 'abCD']
[['' if not x else x[0] for x in q ] for q in [result[:-1]  if len(result) > 2 and result[-2] and result[-2][0].startswith('-') else result for result in  [[[z for z in y if z] for y in (re.findall(r'(?:(^(?:[^A-Z]+-)?)|((?:-[^A-Z]+)?$)|((?:[^A-Z]*)?[A-Z]))', s))] for s in strs]]]


[['foo-', 'A', 'B', 'cmC', 'D', '-bar'],
 ['', 'D', 'E', 'F', ''],
 ['', 'W', 'H', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'V', 'E', 'R', '-foo'],
 ['foo-', 'A', 'B', '(-16)C', 'D', 'E', '-bla'],
 ['foo-', 'abC', 'D', ''],
 ['', 'abC', 'D', '']]
```

Comment: Thanks - might work as well. But Nicks solution is somewhat more elegant.

Comment: Of course, it is not that elegant, but returns the right answers for: foo-abCD (should return ['foo-','abC','D','']) or abCD (should return ['','abC','D',''])

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex in `re.findall`:

```bash
^(?:[^\nA-Z-]+-|)|-[^\nA-Z-]+|[^\nA-Z]*[A-Z]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/koZPOD/2)

**Code:**

```bash
>>> import re
>>> print (re.findall(r'^(?:[^\nA-Z-]+-|)|-[^\nA-Z-]+|[^\nA-Z]*[A-Z]', 'DEF'))
['', 'D', 'E', 'F']
>>> print (re.findall(r'^(?:[^\nA-Z-]+-|)|-[^\nA-Z-]+|[^\nA-Z]*[A-Z]', 'WHATEVER-foo'))
['', 'W', 'H', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'V', 'E', 'R', '-foo']
>>> print (re.findall(r'^(?:[^\nA-Z-]+-|)|-[^\nA-Z-]+|[^\nA-Z]*[A-Z]', 'foo-AB(-16)CDE-bla'))
['foo-', 'A', 'B', '(-16)C', 'D', 'E', '-bla']
>>> print (re.findall(r'^(?:[^\nA-Z-]+-|)|-[^\nA-Z-]+|[^\nA-Z]*[A-Z]', 'foo-ABcmCD-bar'))
['foo-', 'A', 'B', 'cmC', 'D', '-bar']
```

**Explanation:**

- `^(?:[^\nA-Z-]+-|)`: Match start position followed by any char that are not uppercase and `-` and line break OR else an empty match
- `|`: OR
- `-[^\nA-Z-]+`: Match `-` followed by 1+ of any char that are not uppercase and `-` and line break
- `|`: OR
- `[^\nA-Z]*[A-Z]`: Match 0 or more of any char that are not uppercase and line break followed by an uppercase letter

Comment: This doesn't give the correct result for `'DEF'`